# How to tag push request in github

Tags: github, jenkins

After i have pull request - how to push it with specific tag?

Moreover - do you know how to trigger push with specific tag in jenkins?

Thanks#

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins [Git plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) allows you to add  a **Post Build Action** "GIT Publisher".
Here pressing "Add tags" button you can set a tag to push (it can be also a variable from Jenkins environment, as $BUILD_NUMBER).

If the "Create Tag" or "Update tag" option is selected, the tag will be created or updated and pushed at the completion of the build, and the push will fail if a tag with the given name already exists. If the "Create Tag" option is not selected, the push will fail if the tag does not already exist.

Here a [detailed example](http://www.nailedtothex.org/roller/kyle/entry/configuring-automatic-push-by-successfully).